# How to update an individual user auth token in a .NET Core 3.0 app?

Tags: c#, angular, authentication, .net-core

When I created new project in Visual Studio 2019 (.NET Core 3.0 / Angular 8 / Individual user authentication), I can't find the method in .NET Core in which token that I get in Angular is created. I was thinking it should be in login.cs (after scaffolding), but there is no such thing.

Where can I find place where is this token created? I want to just add roles from the user to this token.